# can't scroll when cursor is over div positioned absolute

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, positioning

I am using jquery so that a div positioned absolute follows the mouse cursor, and display as a circle around it.

Issue: I can not scroll the body when the cursor is over the div.

Any workaround or help would be much appreciated!

HTML

```
<div class="follower"></div>
<main class="main">
  <div class="container"> 
  </div>
  <div class="container"> 
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS

```
.follower {
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
border: white 3px solid;
border-radius: 40px;
transition-duration: 250ms;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
position: absolute;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
z-index: 25;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).on('mousemove', (event) => {
 $('.follower').css({
 left: event.clientX,
 top: event.clientY,
  });
 });
```

FIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/xe1h7cda/12/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=xe1h7cda

Comment: Over which div ? and where is the HTML ? and that's not only js it's jquery.

Comment: sorry, added a fiddle in

Answer (score 0):

Add to your follower css:

> pointer-events:none;